# How to set TextColor Xamarin.Forms TableSection?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am a fan of doing as much as possible in xaml, I have aTableView` with a TableSection.

```
<TableView Intent="Menu">
     <TableRoot>
          <TableSection Title="Test Section" TextColor="#FFFFFF">
                <TextCell Text="Test Item" TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
          </TableSection>
     </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

For TextCell `TextColor="#FFFFFF"` seems to work, however whenever I use this attribute on a TableSection I get this:

```
An unhandled exception occurred.
```

Is it possible to change the color of the TableSection with xaml?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've reported it to Xamarin.Forms GitHub, https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2910, let's see how it goes.

Comment: Appears to be fixed in version 3.5 of Xamarin Forms onwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Renderers! I have two blog posts on this here:

Android:[Xamarin.Forms TableView Section Custom Header on Android](https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/21/xamarin-tips-xamarin-forms-android-custom-tableview-section-titles/)

iOS: [Xamarin.Forms TableView Section Custom Header on iOS](https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/21/xamarin-tips-xamarin-forms-ios-custom-tableview-section-titles/)

Basically, create a custom view that inherits `TableView`, then custom renderers that implement custom `TableViewModelRenderer`. From there you can override methods to get the header view for the section title.

Here's what that might look like for Android:

```
public class ColoredTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{

    protected override TableViewModelRenderer GetModelRenderer(Android.Widget.ListView listView, TableView view)
    {
        return new CustomHeaderTableViewModelRenderer(Context, listView, view);
    }

    private class CustomHeaderTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
    {
        private readonly ColoredTableView _coloredTableView;

        public CustomHeaderTableViewModelRenderer(Context context, Android.Widget.ListView listView, TableView view) : base(context, listView, view)
        {
            _coloredTableView = view as ColoredTableView;
        }

        public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);

            var element = GetCellForPosition(position);

            // section header will be a TextCell
            if (element.GetType() == typeof(TextCell))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get the textView of the actual layout
                    var textView = ((((view as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(0) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(1) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(0) as TextView);

                    // get the divider below the header
                    var divider = (view as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(1);

                    // Set the color
                    textView.SetTextColor(_coloredTableView.GroupHeaderColor.ToAndroid());
                    textView.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
                    textView.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
                    divider.SetBackgroundColor(_coloredTableView.GroupHeaderColor.ToAndroid());
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

And the on iOS:

```
public class ColoredTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
            return;

        var coloredTableView = Element as ColoredTableView;
        tableView.WeakDelegate = new CustomHeaderTableModelRenderer(coloredTableView);
    }



    private class CustomHeaderTableModelRenderer : UnEvenTableViewModelRenderer
    {
        private readonly ColoredTableView _coloredTableView;
        public CustomHeaderTableModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
        {
            _coloredTableView = model as ColoredTableView;
        }
        public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return new UILabel()
            {
                Text = TitleForHeader(tableView, section),
                TextColor = _coloredTableView.GroupHeaderColor.ToUIColor(),
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's annoying that this is necessary for such a seemingly basic thing, but I guess that's just what comes of trying to support so many platforms under a single library.

Comment: The Android version seems to change every single `TextCell`, not just the headers.

Comment: Use the `GetCellForPosition(int position, out bool isHeader, out bool nextIsHeader)` variant. It's `private` but reflection helps.

Comment: Any Idea how I can do this for UWP?

Comment: What is that GroupHeaderColor property?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation for TableSection](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TableSectionBase/) you are out of luck. I'm afraid you would have to write a custom renderer for a subclass of the [`TableSection` class](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TableSection/#memberlist) and expose an extra property of type [`Xamarin.Forms.Color`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Color/). Then you would be able to set the color from XAML.

Comment: TableSection is a sealed class. It can't have subclasess.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this color in the base theme (may apply to other widgets too)

In */Resources/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">#434857</item>
```

For Individual Section Titles, the `TextColor` property now seems to work correctly:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="App Settings" TextColor="Red">
```