# How to change the TextSize and Casing in TableView TableSection in Xamarin.UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a `CustomTableView` control which I made from the Xamarin `TableView`. I used custom renderers to change the TextSize and Boldness for Android and iOS with code inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224617/how-to-set-textcolor-xamarin-forms-tablesection).

I want to do the same for UWP, but I have no idea how to achieve this. Specifically I want to make the Text in the TableSections bigger and Make this text start with Uppercase letters as well. Any ideas on how I could achieve this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change the TextSize and Casing in TableView TableSection in Xamarin.UWP

Please check this [code line](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml#L105), Xamarin places TextBlock in the `TableSection` `DataTemplate`. If you want to edit the properties you can do that by adding a `DataTemplate` to your `App.Xaml` file in the UWP project. If you want to edit `FontSize`, you can use the code below. **(Note the FontSize property)**.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TableSectionOne">
        <TextBlock
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            FontSize="55"
            Foreground="{Binding TextColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}"
            Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
            Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource LowerConverter}}"
            Visibility="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource CollapseWhenEmpty}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the UWP Renderer for your customTableView you can set `listview.GroupStyle.FirstOrDefault().HeaderTemplate` manually like below.

```
class CustomTableViewRender : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control != null)
        {
            var listview = Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView;
            listview.GroupStyle.FirstOrDefault().HeaderTemplate = (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["TableSectionOne"];
           
        }
    }   
}
```

Unfortunately, `TableSection` does not support inherit, so we can't extend dependency property for it.

As for the casing of the `Title`, you can simply remove the `Converter={StaticResource LowerConverter}` from the `Text`, and set the `Title` for the `TableView` to a string with with whatever casing you like and it will not be converted to lowercase. So it would end up looking like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TableSectionOne">
        <TextBlock
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            FontSize="55"
            Foreground="{Binding TextColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}"
            Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
            Text="{Binding Title}"
            Visibility="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource CollapseWhenEmpty}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Very helpful, I did make some tweaks to get it working as well as fix the Casing of the Text but this definitely set me on the right track. Thanks! I will edit the answer to include the changes I made and mark this correct